# How to dive into the code-folding topic

Tags: evil, elpy, code-folding

I am sorry for such a broad question but I have no other idea.

I am using Emacs with evil-mode and elpy (for Python files). Not all keyboard shortcuts known from vim are working.
When I ask the search engine of my trust about code folding in emacs I find a lot of stuff. But I am not sure where to start and how all the components work together or blocking or interferring each other.

I am not exactly sure what type of folding I want for my python code. So I want to test some configurations.

But where should I start? Should I concentrate on folding in emacs, evil or elpy?

1. For example I want to toggle fold on the current level (e.g. methodes of a class).
2. Or I want all 1-level folds be closed by default when opening a file.
3. Or I want to toogle fold on the current and all sub-levels.
4. Or maybe there are some more folding-features that are usefull for me that I do not know about yet.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Put that info in you question - ask how to do something specific, which you think will help you toward your goal, whatever that might be.

Comment: [Hide-show](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html) is the classic emacs way though I've found it too clunky to use. There are more promising attempts like https://github.com/shanecelis/hideshow-org. Dunno how complete they are

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/68177/12999