# evil/elpy: Auto-fold when opening a file

Tags: evil, elpy, code-folding

I am using `Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2021-03-28, modified by Debian` with `elpy` and `evil-mode`.

When I open a `py`-file I want everything folded in there by default.

It is still unclear for me how to search for an answer to this wish because I do not know which of the components (elpy, evil, emacs itself, ...) is responsible for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EVil, you can use

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (evil-close-folds)
            ))
```

to close all folds upon entering a file.